# Trading View Pine Script : How to Left Shift indicator, without using offset?

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

Trading View Pine Script : How to Left Shift indicator, without using offset?

Right Shift Works fine.

There is an issue with Left Shift

```
//@version=5
indicator("right_left_shift", overlay=true)

shift = close

plot(shift)

plot(shift[25], color=color.green) //right shift correct


plot(shift[-25], color=color.red) //how to do left shift, without using offset?
```

Error: **Index cannot be a negative value**

Comment: Why don’t you want to use the offset argument? [] in pine is called history reference operator and it cannot be a negative indexed.

Comment: Because, I want to directly perform calculations on a left shifted close of 25 periods

Comment: Offset just moves the line itself, it will not use the values of previous candles. If you want to use the historical data in your calcultions, you shpuld use the `[]` operator. If you want to get the close price of 25 bars ago, you can do `close[25]`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot do a left shift is because that would require you to '*look into the future*'.
This cannot be done, because your script executes once on every historical bar, and while it's running at that bar, at that moment, it's also the '*last bar*' that Pine can see, just like it would be when running in realtime.

See [Excution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Execution_model.html) for more details.

Comment: How do I solve this issue by coding?
I want to plot it in the past such that I can manipulate it with other indicators and set alerts with it.
E.g., I want to set alert when lagging span crosses Ichimoku Cloud in the past.

Comment: You cannot solve this issue, unless you can find a way to know for a fact what the closing price in 25 days will be. In that case, I'd like to know too ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called **repainting**, and more precisely the subtype is *historical repainting*, which means that you want to repaint in the past given current data (so it's like you knew the future). It's ok if you are aware that it is misleading, as it cannot represent real-time data. The [PineScript documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#plotting-in-the-past) has an entry exactly for this purpose:

> The best solution to this problem when developing script for others is
> to plot without an offset by default, but give the option for script
> users to turn on plotting in the past through inputs, so they are
> necessarily aware of what the script is doing, e.g.:
>
> ```
> //@version=5
> indicator("Plotting in the past", "", true)
> plotInThePast = input(false, "Plot in the past")
> pHi = ta.pivothigh(5, 5)
> if not na(pHi)
>     label.new(bar_index[plotInThePast ? 5 : 0], na, str.tostring(pHi, format.mintick) + "\n", yloc = yloc.abovebar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.black, size = size.normal)
> ```

So as you can guess, in practice, you can't plot with an offset without using the offset argument. If you really want to do it manually for whatever reason, you can only do so with annotation entities, such as labels, as done in the example above.